# Program come out of function without executing await

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I'm using Two await function in my program, and first one is working flawlessly but on encountering second await, my program comes out of function without executing that awaitable function and any line after that.

Not giving error and not even crashing.

Tried "wait()", "Running on main thread", "Task Run", "Threading Sleep"..

here a snippet of the code along

```
  private async void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     //this statement works perfectly fine
     var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<LocationPermission>();
      
     //on debugging i found out it return out of function at this point without executing
      var check = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<CameraPermission>();
      
      //None of the code is executed     
      Console.WriteLine("Granted");
      Console.WriteLine("Granted");
  }
```

Comment: Could be cross-thread violation.  Does the RequestPermission access a different thread?  Only time ive had code "randomly" skipped, its always cross-thread violation, which doesnt throw an exception in certain development configurations.

Comment: I think but I'm not sure. If that is the issue, what might be the solution to fix it ?

Comment: Which technology are you using?  In winforms you would use Invoke to access the UI thread.

Comment: I'm using Xamarin forms, But I've tried to invoking it main thread, didn't work.

Comment: Try executing all this inside ui thread, that's what i do for permissions: Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => { ... });

Comment: Yes, already tried but didn't worked not sure why..

Comment: 1) I know you said "doesn't throw any exception", but to be 100% sure, wrap in try/catch, and in the catch, Debug.Writeline(ex.Message). Or something like that. See if there is actually an exception.  2) What happens if you swap the order of the two awaits?  Print something to debug output after first one, and after second one. What I want to know is whether it is always CameraPermission that causes problem, or it is always "the second await".

Comment: It's second await. 
I tried switching the order, camera prompt showed but location's didn't. 
Also it is not going in Catch statement.

Comment: Did you try to add the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and CAMERA permission in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes, I have added it

Comment: 1) If you comment out the second await, does Console.Writeline execute? 2) Although its a different symptom than [RequestPermissionAsync does not return](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin/issues/89), does [Android MainActivity - add this code](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin#android-specific-in-your-baseactivity-or-mainactivity-for-xamarinforms-add-this-code) help? 3) Is there any other code you can show us here? Not sure what, but no one has a solution yet. 4) Can you find an example that works, download and build/run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to use the below method :

```
private async void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await GetPermissions();
}

  public static async Task<bool> GetPermissions()
    {
        bool permissionsGranted = true;

        var permissionsStartList = new List<Permission>()
    {
        Permission.Location,
        Permission.Camera,
     
    };

        var permissionsNeededList = new List<Permission>();
        try
        {
            foreach (var permission in permissionsStartList)
            {
                var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(permission);
                if (status != Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    permissionsNeededList.Add(permission);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(permissionsNeededList.ToArray());

        try
        {
            foreach (var permission in permissionsNeededList)
            {
                var status = Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Unknown;
                //Best practice to always check that the key exists
                if (results.ContainsKey(permission))
                    status = results[permission];
                if (status == Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted || status == Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    permissionsGranted = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    permissionsGranted = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return permissionsGranted;
    }
```